# How to upgrade to Servlet 3.1?

Tags: java, servlets, java-7, java-6

We have `Java 7` installed on out machines but for some reason we deploy with `Servlet 2.4.`

[image]

Where do I download the latest version of Servlet (3.1) and are there specific steps I have to take to install it?

Answer (score 3):

If you use eclipse, there is a way for doing it by auto-generating.

go to the "Properties" --> Project Facets --> Change the "Dynamic Web Module" version to 3.1 ...

Maybe you will have some problems because you have different versions, but you can solve it.

- Upgrate your application server, too.

I hope this helps you

Comment: I was really optimistic when all your steps were actually there but that hasn't gotten rid of the 'undefined error' for request.login() :/